# PHP Get method not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to retrieve the name but why can't I show the whole video inside the embed location?

This is the the whole PHP file that I am working on.

The first box is mainly about uploading the video on to the directory and database.

I am actually having problem with the second box only as the video does not appear.

```
<?php

    include 'connect.php'; //include the php file into this php file

    ?>

<div id="box">
    <form method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <?php

           if(isset($_FILES['video'])){

            $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
            $type = explode('.', $name);
            $type = end($type);
            $size = $_FILES['video']['name'];
            $random_name = rand();
            $tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

            if($type != 'mp4' && $type != 'mp4' && $type != 'wmv'){
                $message = "Video Format Not Supported!";
            }

            else {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$random_name.'.'.$type); 

                mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO videos (id, name, url) 
                VALUE ('', '$name', '$random_name.$type')");
                $message = "Successfully Uploaded!";

            }

            echo "$message"; 

           } 
        ?>


        Select Video : <br/>
        <input type='file' name="video" />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>


</div>


    <div id="box">
        <?php

        $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `id`, `name`, `url` FROM videos");
        while($run = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $video_id = $run['id'];
            $video_name = $run['name'];
            $video_url = $run['url'];

        ?>

        <?php 
              echo $video_name; 


        ?>

        <?php

        $video = $_GET['video'];
        echo "<embed src=`$video` width='560' height='315'></embed>" ;

        ?>


        <?php

        }
        ?>


    </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `src="$video_url"` ? If not then what's the use of that query there?

Comment: What you did @dodoMi can easily backfire. Here you used these backticks inside a quoted context, what isn't dangerous (see the note in the link I added). If you use it in PHP's context (not captured in quotes), it will be executed as a shell command, according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: Tried all 3 but still not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have backticks instead of quotes in your HTML. Change them to single or double quotes, e.g.:

```
    echo "<embed src='$video' width='560' height='315'></embed>" ;
                     ^      ^
```

Comment: I know. He was using backticks, I changed them to single quotes.

Comment: @AntonGildebrand did u read the question the user was using `` and @Barmar shows to use '' instead of ``

Answer (score 1):

You should have

```
if (isset($_GET['video'])) {
   $video = $_GET['video'];
   echo '<embed src="'.$video.'" width="560" height="315"></embed>';
}
```

So people can't access the page without entering a video id

Comment: `===true` is not needed

Comment: I tried this but the video is still not coming out. :(

Is it because of the query?

Comment: Give me about 5 minutes, I will post another answer. What is the directory of the video? And the directory of the php file? Also what are the rows that are being echoed from the query?

Comment: Btw, are you trying to get only one video to show? Or more than one?

Comment: Do you need me to paste the whole PHP file? I am using localhost.

Comment: All I need to know is, what are the values of the video in the database. Give me an example of the id, url and name and then I can try to resolve it

Comment: The ID is AI.

The name will be the file name. etc(TheIntro.wmv)

I set the url with a random name so it is a random int like 20249.wmv

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it will require you to change your database. But should work. Just read the commented out instructions I made to use it.

```
<div id="box">
  <?php
   if (isset($_GET['video'])) {
    $video = $_GET['video'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `id`='$video'");
     $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
     if ($count!=0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $video_id   = $row['id'];
        $video_name = $row['name'];
        $video_url  = $row['url'];
        echo $video_name;
        echo '<embed src="'.$video_url.'" height="315px" width="560px">';
        //echp <video height="315px" width="560px" controls><source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video> 
        //Use the above code if you want a html5 video player.
     } else {
        echo 'Video does not exist!';
     }
   } else {
      echo 'Please enter a video id!';
   }
   /*
    How to use it:
    Create a database called "videos"
    Insert the following three columns:
     id   = varchar(225) as `primary_key`
     name = varchar(225);
     url  = varchar(225);
    To insert a video, you will need to create
    a random id for the video and insert it
    into the mysql database. Example
      $rand = rand(111111111,999999999);
      $id   = md5($rand);
      //example $id = 3174143713413051830531
      $name = "Random video name";
      $url  = "http:/localhost/websitename/videos/nameofvideo.mp4";
      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `videos` VALUES ('$id','$name','$url')");
    Then to select the video you will go to a page
    video.php?video=[video id here];
    video.php?video=3174143713413051830531
    then the php will select the url for the video
    id = 3174143713413051830531
    and it will play that video. 
    example: video_url would be http://localhost/websitename/videos/nameofvideo.mp4
    If you have any further questions,
    feel free to ask me. Thanks
   */
  ?>
</div>
```

Hope this works. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to write that out! Apparently, my database has been created like this too so I guess I don't have to alter anymore. 
However do I have to create a new php named video.php for the user to view the video? I am sorry because I am still new to php.

Comment: Copy and paste the code in a file called video.php and then create a table the way that is explained in the answer. Then create a folder called 'videos' in the same directory as the video.php. And in the 'videos' folder the videos will be stored there. Video id will be randomly generated and will identify the video, video name will be the name, and video url will be the url. The id will be used to get info from the video making it different from others.

Comment: I am truly sorry as I am getting really confused.

I would then have to create a href to link to the video php right?

And can I just add the randomID function at the same page?

Comment: I added the whole PHP file at the opening post.

Comment: video.php will be the page that plays the video. For a certain video, you would go to video.php?video=[video_id]. For the upload part, add `$id=md5(rand(111111111,999999999)); $name="Video name"; $url="http://localhost/websitename/videos/[video_filename]";` And insert those into the database. If you are learning php, it is best that you go with something simple to learn the basics of php before going into the complicated stuff.